# PHP UNIT TEST METHODS

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Please take a look at the code below. We've got a class FightService, which implements a logic of a fight between two heroes. After the fight one of the heroes may lose some health points.

How can I implement a test for `FightService::fight()` method in correct way?

Feel free to refactor any code if you think it's needed.

```php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

interface HeroInterface
{
    public function getAttack(): int;

    public function getDefence(): int;

    public function getHealthPoints(): int;

    public function setHealthPoints(int $healthPoints);
}

class DamageCalculator
{
    const DAMAGE_RAND_FACTOR = 0.2;

    public static function calculateDamage(HeroInterface $attacker, HeroInterface $defender): int
    {
        $damage = 0;

        if ($attacker->getAttack() > $defender->getDefence()) {
            $baseDamage = $attacker->getAttack() - $defender->getDefence();

            $factor = $baseDamage * self::DAMAGE_RAND_FACTOR;

            $minDamage = $baseDamage - $factor;
            $maxDamage = $baseDamage + $factor;

            $damage = mt_rand($minDamage, $maxDamage);
        }

        return $damage;
    }
}

class FightService
{
    public function fight(HeroInterface $attacker, HeroInterface $defender)
    {
        $damage = DamageCalculator::calculateDamage($attacker, $defender);

        $defender->setHealthPoints($defender->getHealthPoints() - $damage);
    }
}

class FightServiceTest extends TestCase {

    public function testFight()
    {
        // here my test but not working i can't pass parameters to interface so i'm not sure what i'm doing ?

        $playerOne = rand(1,100);
        $playerTwo = rand(1,100);
        $this->assertInstanceOf(
            FightService::class,
            FightService::fight($playerOne, $playerTwo)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't pass parameters to interface. You need to create a class that `implements` this interface and them create object of this class to use in tests:


class Hero implements HeroInterface(){

  public function getAttack(): int{
    // add some code
  }

    public function getDefence(): int{
    // add some code
  }

    public function getHealthPoints(): int{
    // add some code
  }

    public function setHealthPoints(int $healthPoints){
    // add some code
  }
}

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

Comment: `Feel free to refactor any code if you think it's needed.`

Comment: Yes, you could avoid creating a new class by mocking interface: [see](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test-doubles.html).

But I think for a start you should have a test which works and answer the question with a class then after removing the class and try to go further.

Comment: Awesome thx duo, what about this fun 
    public function testFight(HeroInterface $interface)
    {
     // implement the test
     $rand = rand(1,100);

     $interface->getAttack($rand);
     $interface->getDefence($rand);
     $interface->getHealthPoints($rand);
     
        $this->assertInstanceOf(FightService::fight());
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static calls are fixed dependencies and should be avoided. If you use dependency injection you can replace the dependencies with stubs and/or mocks.

With that the DamageCalculator can be an interface as well and allow for different implementations.

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

interface HeroInterface {
  public function getAttack(): int;

  public function getDefence(): int;

  public function getHealthPoints(): int;

  public function setHealthPoints(int $healthPoints);
}

interface DamageCalculatorInterface {

  public function calculateDamage(HeroInterface $attacker, HeroInterface $defender): int;
}

class FightService {
  /**
   * @var DamageCalculatorInterface
   */
  private $_damageCalculator;

  public function __construct(DamageCalculatorInterface $damageCalculator) {
    $this->_damageCalculator = $damageCalculator;
  }

  public function fight(HeroInterface $attacker, HeroInterface $defender) {
    $damage = $this->_damageCalculator->calculateDamage($attacker, $defender);

    $defender->setHealthPoints($defender->getHealthPoints() - $damage);
  }
}

class FightServiceTest extends TestCase {

  public function testFight(): void {
    $attacker = $this->createMock(HeroInterface::class);
    $defender = $this->createMock(HeroInterface::class);
    $defender
      ->expects($this->once())
      ->method('getHealthPoints')
      ->willReturn(21);
    $defender
      ->expects($this->once())
      ->method('setHealthPoints')
      ->with(16);

    $damageCalculator = $this->createMock(DamageCalculatorInterface::class);
    $damageCalculator
      ->expects($this->once())
      ->method('calculateDamage')
      ->with($attacker, $defender)
      ->willReturn(5);

    $fightService = new FightService($damageCalculator);
    $fightService->fight($attacker, $defender);
  }
}
```